# How to completely stop autodevops pipeline in gitlab 15.7.0?

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

Whenever i try to merge requests the pipeline automatically runs and gets stuck, this makes the merge request unable to approv.

I tried disabling the Auto Devops, but this doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Check first if, for testing on a project, you can follow "[Disable Auto DevOps at the project level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/#at-the-project-level)":

> Prerequisites:
>
> - You must have at least the `Maintainer` role for the project.
> - Ensure your project does *not* have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` present.
>   If present, your CI/CD configuration takes precedence over the Auto DevOps pipeline.
>
> To enable Auto DevOps for a project:
>
> - On the top bar, select Main menu > Projects and find your project.
> - On the left sidebar, select Settings > CI/CD.
> - Expand Auto DevOps.
> - Select the Default to Auto DevOps pipeline checkbox.
> - Optional but recommended. Add the base domain.
> - Optional but recommended. Choose the deployment strategy.
> - Select Save changes.
>
> GitLab triggers the Auto DevOps pipeline on the default branch.
>
> **To disable it, follow the same process and clear the Default to Auto DevOps pipeline checkbox.**

Comment: And tes, you can disable it [at the instance level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/#at-the-instance-level) also, for all projects.